# command export is not in $PATH, yet it can be executed

Tags: bash, shell

bash command `export` can not be found in `$PATH`, yet it is available to execute. Similar to that is `source`. Why is it this way ? Thanks for any noble answer...

Answer (score 5):

It's a builtin. Read more about it here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html

Comment: If you enter the text between quotes here: "type export" the shell will respond with export is a shell builtin.